# A compact note on equivalent metrics.

Tags: metric-spaces, problem-solving

I am a graduate student of mathematics.While studying metric spaces,we often encounter equivalent metrics.I know the definition (that equivalent metrics induce the same topology)and also know that $d_1,d_2,d_\infty$  are equivalent on $\mathbb R^n$.But still,I am not quite used to equivalent metrics and feel shaky while doing problems.Can someone suggest some text,note or link that discusses properties of equivalent metrics(such as properties preserved by equivalent metric) along with problems on it?

Comment: Can you mention some problems that gave you some trouble?

Comment: @DonThousand It is not the problems that gave me trouble,I am feeling shaky when I prove certain theorems on it.

Comment: Not quite what you are asking, but possibly my 16 September 2006 sci.math post [Lipschitz, uniformly, and topologically equivalent metrics](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/M_rwL68ibPs/m/WokSnPuvazsJ) (some additions made in this [4 October 2006 version](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/M_rwL68ibPs/m/10wJvtJcgp4J)) could be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for equivalent metrics, the generated topology is the same, i. e., from a topologist's perspective, there is no difference between spaces with equivalent metrics. E. g.

- all continuous functions remain continous,
- the product topology remains the same
- in  two such Hausdorff local compact topological groups the (existing) Haar measure is the same etc.